# Result is different for different calculation sequence in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server will handle accuracy by guess and other policies, sometimes its policy will return a wrong result.

This SQL prepares the data:

```
select cast(0.3 as decimal(20,5)) Fee
    , 1010 AS Q1
    , 101 AS Q2
    , CAST( 0.1415949300 AS DECIMAL(18,10)) as Rate
INTO TTT
```

This SQL returns the data and show the wrong result:

```
SELECT Fee*Q1/Q2*Rate Result1
    , Rate*Fee*Q1/Q2 Result2
FROM TTT
```

Result1 is 0.424785 and Result2 is 0.424784. You can see these two results are different.

This can be reproduced on SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.7001.0) and SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2000.5). The client version is SQL Server Management Studio v18.6 (15.0.18338.0)

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2424e/1

Comment: What is expected result

Comment: Its a result of the way SQL Server maintains its max precision and scale during mathematical operations see [Link 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/automatic-decimal-rounding-issue), [Link 2](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=92608), [Link 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: This does work. So normally division should be handle at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, your assumption that 'division should be handled at the end' is mistaken.

As in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> When two operators in an expression have the same precedence level,
> **they're evaluated left to right based on their position** in the
> expression. For example, in the expression that is used in the
> following SET statement, the subtraction operator is evaluated before
> the addition operator.

Hence, `Rate` after `Fee` or `Fee` after `Rate` does, indeed, affect the result.